# SSMS 2008 - Can't Add Maintenance Plans

Tags: sql, ssms

Trying to save a new Maintenance Plan using SSMS 2008 and receiving error:

`Apply to target server failed for Job 'DB Backup.createDBBackup'`

The connection has been verified.

Is [dbo].[sp_add_maintenance_plan] suppose to be found under:

**Databases > System Databases > msdb > Programmability > Stored Procedures**

*OR*

**Databases > System Databases > msdb > Programmability > Stored Procedures > System Stored Procedures**

If you require more info, don't hesitate to ask.

Thanks,
Alex

**UPDATE**

The maintance plan now creates .bak files but it seems I can't run MAINTENACE CLEANUP TASK. Could it be that master.dbo.xp_delete_file can't be found. Is there a way to reset that as well?

Comment: Do you have the Integration Services service installed on the server?

Comment: Under Integration Services I have **Data Profile Viewer** and **Execute Package Utility**. The server is missing Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools component.

Comment: But do you have the service installed on the machine?

Comment: I have SQL Server Integration Services 10.0 running on the machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a system stored procedure in msdb.

Comment: I use to have an issue **Deleting Jobs**, I then added dbo.sp_delete_job under **Databases > System Databases > msdb > Programmability > Stored Procedures** - Deleting now works. Could my **msdb** be missing Stored Procedures? How do you go about fixing the msdb?

Comment: There's a script in the install folder called instmsdb.sql.  Running that should put the objects back.

Comment: The maintance plan now creates .bak files but it seems I can't run MAINTENACE CLEANUP TASK. Could it be that master.dbo.xp_delete_file can't be found. Is there a way to reset that as well?